# Strip everything except API from C++ static lib?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++14

I have a static library that I need to remove unwanted symbols from. There are only two external facing public API functions.

I'm struggling to strip the archive such that only the external API is exposed in the library.If I use something like:

```
objcopy --keep-global-symbol=some-mangled-cpp-symbol-name liblibrary.a liblibrary.a && ranlib liblibrary.a
```

...then I get a linker error when I attempt to link against the new archive:

```
$ g++ -I $(pwd)/install/include -L$(pwd)/build -o main test_app.cpp -llibrary.a
/usr/bin/ld: error in ...liblibary.a(filename.cpp.o)(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created
```

Followed by a segfault when the code is run.

Any fixes or alternative techniques for getting rid of all the extraneous symbols?

Comment: Looks like you accidentally also stripped a wanted symbol.  The way I get rid of exposing extraneous symbols is by putting those things in an anonymous namespace.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the anonymous namespace bit for me @Eljay - that might be really handy for me.

Comment: @BrianSidebotham: It's functionally-equivalent to declaring them `static`. Which I presume you would have done if you wanted to hide them and make them inaccessible to outside code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a static library, there is no such thing as "external facing public API functions". Any function that was not declared `static` is *equally part* of the library, as far as the compiler and linker are concerned. Any code could declare those functions and link with your library and thereby access them.

C++ as a language does not deal in "libraries"; it deals in "translation units" (.cpp files). So its scoping is limited to either everyone or just this TU.

However, C++20 has a tool way to declare functions that are, for all intents and purposes, internal to a library: modules. A name that is module scoped but not exported cannot be declared and accessed by code outside of that module. As such, it would be theoretically possible to strip out any non-exported, module scoped code that isn't used by the module itself.

Comment: I'm not sure OP is actually after removing code from the library.  Rather he wants to prelink all the internal calls and not have helper functions appear in the library symbol table.  Or that's how I interpret the task.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's the same thing, said a different way. It still ultimately relies on being able to determine what a "helper function" *is*, which is just not a thing in C++ pre-modules.

Comment: I definitely agree that there's a problem with identifying which symbols ought to be public (OP wants to list them on the command-line).  But there certainly is a difference between removing function bodies (machine code) which are unreachable from entrypoints, vs leaving the machine code intact, resolving calls to it from inside the library, and only removing the signpost.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Is there a difference? If you can do the latter, you can do the former. It may require a bit more effort, but 100% of the information needed to do it is already there.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for the reminder of the term Translation Unit. Had totally forgot about the term and it helps me understand what I can and can't do. Our only option here is to move everything to a monolith source and use static for everything we don't want exposed.